# Orthogonal projection in Inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

Let V be $n$-Dimensional ($n\ge1$) inner product space .

Let $T:V \rightarrow V$ be a linear map which maintains   $ T^2=T$ , $\forall v \in V\ ||Tv||\le||v||$.

Prove that there is exists a subspace $U\subseteq V$ ,$0 \le dimU\le n $, such that T is the Orthogonal projection on U.

I tried to prove that $ImT \perp KerT $.But I don't know how to use the fact that $||Tv||\le||v||$.Maybe Cauchy–Schwarz inequality can helps somehow ?

Comment: So your thoughts please...?

Comment: just updated in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is good, let's start defining those quantities

$$Im(T) = \{ x \in V : x = Tv, v \in V \}$$

$$Ker(T) = \{ y \in V : Ty = 0 \}.$$

We need to show that for any $x \in Im(T)$ and $y \in Ker(T)$ we must have $\left < x, y\right > = 0.$

As $x \in Im(T)$, there is a $v \in V$ such that $$x = Tv.$$

By the idempotent property, we also have

$$T(x) = T(Tv) = Tv = x. $$

and since $y \in Ker(T)$ we get $T(x + ay) = T(x) + aT(y) = T(x) = x$ for any scalar $a$.

Using the inequality we get $\| x \| = \| T(x+ ay) \| \leq \|x + ay \|.$

As the above is true for an arbitrary chosen $a$, the result now follows.

Comment: I mean to say that $\|x \| \leq \| x + ay \| \iff \left < x,y \right > = 0$

Comment: can you show me how to prove it without assuming $<x,y>=<y,x>$?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean NOT assuming $\left < x ,y \right > = \left < y,x \right >$?

Comment: because in $\mathbb{C}$ $<x,y>= \overline{\ <y,x>}$

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, $\| x + ay \|^2 = \|x \|^2 + \left < x , y \right > + \left <y,x \right > + \|a y \|^2 = \|x \|^2 + \bar{a}\left < x , y \right > + \bar{a\left <x,y \right >} + \| ay \|^2 = \|x \|^2 + 2Re(\bar{a}\left < x , y \right >) + \| ay \|^2$ is this where you were stuck?

Comment: So you got 
$0≤2Re(a¯<x,y>) +||ay||^2$  for any scalar a.why does it shows that $<x,y>=0$

Comment: With $c >0$, let $a = -c\left<x,y \right >$. If $y \neq 0$, select $c = \frac{1}{\|y\|^2}$.

Comment: ok, I took $a$ as you Mentioned and I got: $2|<x,y>|^2≤<x,y>^2$

Comment: but how does it shows that $<x,y>$=0 ?

Comment: Subtract $\| \left < x, y \right> \|^2$ from both sides. Take square root.

Comment: I didn't understand how to finish it as well.. I’ll be glad if you could be a little more specific

Comment: Which part? I just explained the last part.

Comment: It shows $\left < x, y \right > = 0$ because $\| \left < x, y \right > \| = 0 $

Comment: You missed a step. When you get to $\left < x,y\right >^2 \leq \| \left < x,y\right > \|^2 $.

Comment: Missed your message, now its clear thanks.

Comment: great, tnx! it helped me a lot!